# Intercept routes before controller is created

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the new attribute routes in MVC 5.0. How can I intercept the routes to be able to replace `{culture}` with the current culture?

Could this be done with a custom route handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in the BeginRequest event on Global.asax. We do it on the GetVaryByCustomString since we use output cache and need to set a different cache to each language.

Comment: Yes,I will use that to ... But the problem is that I need to set constraint so that {culture} can take only certain values ... Don't I need to do that on route creation?

Comment: There you go, it is in route declaration and not creation. See this (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) for a more detailed example and explanation. You will need a regex with all your allowed culture values.