# Routing Controllers asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In our application users can create objects and give them a name.  This data is stored in the database with a typeId.  I have an api controller that can currently be called, with a name like

```
api/data
```

This controller has the basic Get, Put, Post and Delete methods.

Now i would like users to be able to call this controller by object type.  So if they setup 3 different objects and call them company, contact and project, i would like them to be able to call the api/data controller, using these names, similar to this

```
api/company
api/contact
api/project
```

I do not know these object types unitl runtime, so i cannot code these manually.

Now i also have other controllers that i do not want effected by this, so if i have a normal controller called page, then i still want to be able to call it by

```
api/page
```

Is there a way i can do this?  Almost intercept a call to a controller, see if the name is equal to a name i have in the database, and if so pass it to the data controller, else let it process as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should

HomeController:

```
ActionResult Index(string name)
{
// check if name exists in DB
}
```

I didn't see other way to do what you want even by editing routes... or maybe if you do routes with DB but well...

Answer (score 0):

As far as you are using api controller, you may play with RoutePrefix and Route annotations. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [Route("company")]
    public IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel> GetCompanies() 
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

But this may conflict with default route definition. If so, try to specifically define your routes for this controller:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CompanyApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/company/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "DataController" , id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: I do not know these object types until runtime, so i cannot code these in, but need a way to "redirect" at runtime based on a value.

Comment: do you know the ones that are not from the db? if so, see my answer. It's basically the reverse of this answer.

Comment: If you don't know exact names, the system will not be able to find method name. You can convert your names to additional URI parameters and specify one special route for that

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a route for each object in your db, or rather each object not from the db, and have all others route to a default path. You may want to look at using regex with your routing, if you are able to prefix the object names at all.

Comment: cant create a route for all names that havent been created as the user can pick the name, although it isnt allowed any spaces. Is there not a way to intercept the call to a controller and "redirect" it based on some rules?

Comment: In that case you would need to do it in the BeginRequest event on Global.asax. This might have more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579327/intercept-routes-before-controller-is-created

Answer (score 0):

Web API routing uses fall-through logic, so start off by declaring your known routes first, then have a generic handler to catch all other requests and handle them accordingly. For example, use the following code when setting up your `HttpConfiguration`:

```
// Define all known routes using attributes.
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// Generic route to handle all other requests
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DynamicRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{dataType}",
    defaults: new { controller = "data" }
);
```

Then in your `DataController` you can have actions that take the dataType as a parameter:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string dataType, ...)
{  ...  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do what i want by using RoutePrefix attribute on controller with an extra MapRoute, with a constraint applied to it.

Here is the code, if someone else is trying to do something similar

First add a routePrefix to the controller that you want to call

```
[RoutePrefix("api/{myCustomName}")]
public MyController : ApiController { 

}
```

Now in my WebApiConfig file, i needed to add the following lines

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// handle calling MyController using custom name
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ModuleDataApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{myCustomName}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController" },
    constraints: new { moduleType = new MyCustomRouteConstraint() }
);
```

Now create the constraint that checks if there is a valid match.  In my code, i have populated a text file with the details if the file doesnt exist, and i will delete/refresh this when a new custom name is added.  I believe this would perform better then a database query everytime, since i would probably have about 20 name/value pairs in here at the very most.

So create your constraint like so

```
public class MyCustomRouteConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    private DbContext _context;
    private static object fileLockObject = new object();

    public MyCustomRouteConstraint ()
    {
        _context = new DbContext();
    }

    public bool Match(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var appDataPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/CustomNameRouteCache.txt");

        // lock variable so no 2 or more threads can try to create file at once
        lock (fileLockObject)
        {
            var list = new List<MyRouteModel>();

            // check if our cache file exists, if not, lets create it
            if (!File.Exists(appDataPath))
            {
                using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(appDataPath))
                {
                    // get all modules
                    var names = _context.CustomNames.ToList();

                    foreach (var item in names)
                    {
                        list.Add(Mapper.Map<MyRouteModel>(item));
                    }

                    // serialize the list to the file in json format
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

                    // write to file
                    writer.Write(json);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                // open file and get json contents
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(appDataPath))
                {
                    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyRouteModel>>(json);
                }
            }

            // lets search our list and see if this value is in our modules
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.Name.Equals(values[parameterName].ToString()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now this seems to work perfectly, i can call MyController using the following paths, or any others that are created by the user at runtime

```
api/company/
api/contact/
api/project/
api/whateveryouwant/
```

Hope this help someone else trying to do something similar